# Unit Testing for Conditional Rendering of Components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, conditional-statements, enzyme

pretty new to the React World and would like to ask how to test for Conditional Rendering.

Home.js

```
export default function Home() {
   const { user } = useAuth(); 
   
   return (
      <>
         <Container className="pt-5 mt-5">
            {user ? <LoggedInHome /> : <LoggedOutHome />}
         </Container>
      </>
   ); 
}
```

Home.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow, configure} from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import Home from "../Home";
import LoggedInHome from "../Dashboard";
import LoggedOutHome from "../LoggedOutHome";
import { AuthContext } from "../AuthContext";

let wrapper;
const user = { displayName: "James", email: "g@gmail.com", 
emailVerified: true };

describe("Homepage", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
            <Home />
        </AuthContext.Provider>
   );
  });

  it("should display LoggedOutHome if not logged in", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(LoggedOutHome)).toHaveLength(0)
  });

  it("should display LoggedInHome if logged in", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(LoggedInHome)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)

Expected length: 1
Received length: 0
Received object: {}

  27 |
  28 |     it("should display LoggedInHome if logged in", () => {
> 29 |         expect(wrapper.find(LoggedInHome)).toHaveLength(1);
     |                                         ^
  30 |     });
  31 | });
```

Seems like both LoggedInHome and LoggedOutHome both have length of 0. Not sure what is happening here. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Given you're just getting started, I'd suggest using https://testing-library.com/ for a bunch of reasons, I will keep it short:
- Enzyme adapters are not ready for react 17 and 18
- Enzyme tests tend to 'know' too much about underlying implementation. Which makes harder do maintain test.

That said, take some time to read testing library docs. Do your best to mock as little as you can and try to replicate as close as possible actual user interactions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not mounting `Home`, but `Homepage`?

Generally speaking, you want to mock the `getAuth()` function to return a user and to return `undefined` in order to check for both values.

Comment: Sorry, its supposed to be Home not Homepage, edited it. How do you go about passing the mock value of user to be passed into Home?